# NSOutlineView: click to edit doesn't select text

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a view-based NSOutlineView, and I'm working on making items editable. If I click on an item to edit it, it starts with the insertion point where I clicked, rather than selecting the whole text. Pressing enter/return to edit does select the whole text.

Comparing my code to the TableViewPlayground sample, which doesn't have this problem, I haven't been able to find any significant differences. The only difference I found was that the sample uses bindings, but when I tried making that change it didn't help.

My cell view's text view has my view controller set as its delegate (I even re-set it in `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` to be sure), but `control:textShouldBeginEditing:` never gets called. I thought maybe I'd be able to select the text from there.

Is there something I can do to make the text automatically selected on click-to-edit? Is there another way I can be notified when an edit session starts, so I can select the text manually?

Comment: The code is [here on github](https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/commit/ab542bba4b7d4fd7a5af24b931cb04327817c188), minus setting the text view's delegate since that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom class named `MyTextField` that extends `NSTextField` class.

```
class MyTextField: NSTextField {

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        currentEditor()?.selectAll(self)
    }
}
```

Go to the storyboard, set the `NSTextField` control's class.
Done.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading apple's sample project "DragNDropOutlineView" (google it)

In this sample, almost all the functionalities done using outline view can be seen(like edit,drag,drop,adding nodes,remove nodes etc..).

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: That sample isn't view-based, so it doesn't help my situation.